# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: when using realm database, no method found

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

I have included Realm in a project, and have followed the documentation. But whenever I compile and run the app, i get the following error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: org.innoversetech.wifinity, PID: 8391
      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method loadLibrary(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lcom/getkeepsafe/relinker/ReLinker; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker' appears in /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes16.dex)
      at io.realm.internal.RealmCore.loadLibrary(RealmCore.java:60)
      at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:200)
      at org.innoversetech.wifinity.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:17)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6496)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I have been at this for hours now and I cannot understand what the problem is. Here is my code for MyApplication class:

```
import android.app.Application;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle for app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.innoversetech.wifinity"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            proguardFile 'D:/Code/Android/KillMe/Wifinity/app/proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //dependencies
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
    compile 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.5'
    compile 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.race604.waveloading:library:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.Yalantis:GuillotineMenu-Android:1.2'
    compile 'net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:+@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:+@aar'
    compile 'com.diegodobelo.expandingview:expanding-view:0.9.4'
    compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recyclerview:0.9.25'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15'
    compile 'com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.github.KeepSafe:ReLinker:1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0-alpha1'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the project level gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the error I get when I remove the ReLinker libraries:

```
 Process: org.innoversetech.wifinity, PID: 22788
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/getkeepsafe/relinker/ReLinker;
        at io.realm.internal.RealmCore.loadLibrary(RealmCore.java:60)
        at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:200)
        at org.innoversetech.wifinity.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:17)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6496)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/lib/arm, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/org.innoversetech.wifinity-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at io.realm.internal.RealmCore.loadLibrary(RealmCore.java:60) 
        at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:200) 
        at org.innoversetech.wifinity.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:17) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6496) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 14 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: That error may come from Realm... But the error is another library you gave `com.getkeepsafe.relinker`

Comment: Should i remove it? Then i get another error

Comment: For example, you have conflicting libraries... `com.github.KeepSafe:ReLinker:1.1`, and that method might not exist in that version

Comment: I get the same error if i remove any one of them. I added them both out of sheer frustration >.<

Comment: The realm documentation does not claim that you need this ReLinker library, so what's the other error?

Comment: Updated the error in the quesiton. Pls have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152971/discussion-between-muhammad-muneeb-ul-haq-and-cricket-007).

Comment: I would like to think there is a problem with including JitPack dependencies and using Realm, which prompted this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2608 However, I might suggest that you either 1) create a smaller, separate example app (don't include so many libraries), and 2) posting a Github issue, since it could just be a bug

Comment: Here's a funny thing i just stumbled upon. The app works perfectly if i generate an apk and install it manually. But as long as i install it from android studio, it crashes. I have implemented the exact same stuff in another app with a handful of libraries, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well, you don't need Android Studio to install the app. :) https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html#DebugMode

Comment: That is exactly how i m rolling right now xD

Comment: I do find it strange that Android Studio would interfere with that process, because I'm pretty sure that's the Gradle function that is ran. You might want to try disabling Instant Run, though

Answer (score 0):

Realm depends on `implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.2'` (basically "compile"), but I think your issue is caused by

> ```
> compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recyclerview:0.9.25'
> ```

Because version 0.9.25 brings in Realm version 2.2.1, so that can clash against Realm 3.5.0.

A possible solution would be to copy the sources of `RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter` to your code so that it doesn't depend on old things.

Another thing you can do is just not use `RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter`, and give a try for `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` in `realm-android-adapters`.

A clean+rebuild might also help.

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate use,

```
realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```